# Audit question should not have been closed in the first place

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I was just hit by an audit question in the close queue. Specifically it was this question: [After Maven build jar changes do not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133298/after-maven-build-jar-changes-do-not-show) from this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15968950

While I agree that it could have been worded better (and I have since edited it to be a bit clearer), it was closed because it was "unclear, what you're asking". I disagree. This person built a project, gave us the command he used to do so and then found that the artefact did not include his changes. Shouldn't it be removed from the list of audit questions?

Comment: Another user's failed audit on same question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15850598

Comment: The reopen vote should remove it from being considered as a audit going forward.

Comment: @NathanOliver Great, thanks. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure so I didn't want to make it answer.  reopen votes age away so I don't what happens if the vote(s) do age away and the Q stays closed.  I do know an up vote will remove it as an audit.

Comment: Presumably you understand given build tool well enough to consider question reasonable, but for me judging just by the answer it looks like OP just randomly grab some command that may not even build anything, did not look at meaning of arguments and definitely did not look at build log. I strongly suspect the question missing MCVE and shows no research - but I can't really judge it as I don't know this toolchain.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The OP may not be an expert at that build tool (Maven), but using those arguments is quite reasonable in many cases. Independent of whether the question is good or not however, I feel there is enough doubt there that it should not be an audit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting to re-open should keep question from audit pool at least for some time (not sure what happens when vote ages out).

I think you've done all that could be done - edit, vote to re-open and up-vote as you consider it solid question with enough information to reproduce the issue with given toolchain (Java + maven).

---

I personally would skip the question if I see it in close votes reviews (no idea about maven - so can't judge it). If question of similar quality would show up for tags I know about I'd keep it closed as "missing MCVE".